# How to parallelize ArrayList operations with Java Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, arraylist

I have the Array list of passwords. And I want to check if file decrypts with that password. I want to use threads for applying the string transformations like adding the number to the end of the string. What is the best way to do this using java threads or threadpool?

```
for (String pass : passwordDictionary) {
               setPassword(password);
               decrypt(secret)
               setPassword(password+numbers);
               decrypt(secret)
```

Comment: Best way is to use [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).

Comment: java 8 have parallel streaming API for such task, you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible ways is to use `Stream.parallel()`:

```
passwordDictionary.stream().parallel().forEach(password -> { 
               setPassword(password);
               decrypt(secret)
               setPassword(password+numbers);
               decrypt(secret)
})
```

Comment: Assuming he is on Java8

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used lambdas in Java yet but sounds really interesting. Is it possible to know how many treads does .parallel initialize?

Comment: @Wideem a parallel stream uses `Fork/Join framework`. So it can have `N-1` threads, where `N` is number of the processors by default. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html  and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html